# Ckeditor Duplicate Node Copier Function For IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ckeditor

I have a Node Duplicating Function.

This function May be Alternate for setHtml problem on IE.

i want to copy Attributes and innerText (for EveryNode).

My Problem Is Every Node Have **(May Be)Text**+ Some Nodes.

I want to copy  Node  By Node As Below mentioned condition

1.Current Node's Text only (not InnerNodes Text)

2.Child Nodes Duplicate With all its Attribute

My Function is below:

```
 function NodeDuplicateCreator(DummyNode, RealNode) {
            var XnodefromReal = RealNode.getChildren();
            for (var i = 0; i < XnodefromReal.count(); i++) {
                if (XnodefromReal.getItem(i).$.nodeType == 1) {
                    var xnode = XnodefromReal.getItem(i);
                    var xnodeName = xnode.getName();
                    var NewNodeGen = DummyNode.getElementsByTag(xnodeName).getItem(0);
                    if (NewNodeGen == null) {
                        NewNodeGen = EditorInstance.document.createElement(xnodeName);
                        NewNodeGen.appendTo(DummyNode);
                    }
                    NodeDuplicateCreator(NewNodeGen, xnode);
                }
            }
        }
```

Please improve it as my requirement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `copyAttributes(node)` function for attribute

try below code to textcontent+childnodes

```
if(XnodefromReal.getItem(i).$.nodeType == 1) 
{
//for childnodes
}
else if(XnodefromReal.getItem(i).$.nodeType == 3) 
{
//for text content
}
```